# Truth Table for Binary Operation

Tags: java, boolean, truthtable

I am new to coding. Taking a course online and for some reason I can not grasp the lab this week. We need to create a truth table. One for AND and one for OR. Some of the code is given to us and idea is to use boolean..

this is what I have so far.. Not much but any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Also, please be gently..I have figured out the labs each week but for some reason I am just not grasping this one.

```
public class TruthTables {

    public static void printTruthTableValue(boolean p, boolean q, String 
    logicalOperation)}

        printTruthTableValue(true,true, logicalOperation);
        printTruthTableValue(true,false, logcialOperation);
        printTruthTableValue(false,true, logcialOperation);
        printTruthTableValue(false,false, logicalOperation);
    }   
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTruthTable("and");
        System.out.println();
        printTruthTable("or");
    }
```

The output needs to be

```
p  q  p AND q
-------------
T  T  T
T  F  F
F  T  F
F  F  F
```

while that for OR is

```
p  q  p OR q
-------------
T  T  T
T  F  T
F  T  T
F  F  F
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with Java, not javascript?  Also your code sample seems to be missing a definition for `printTruthTable`

Comment: What have you tried? What particularly do you have problems with? For me this code looks like the input of the initial task (I may be wrong). We cannot do your homework for you, you need some input to start helping you.

Answer (score 0):

As Thymine said, you appear to be missing a definition for `printTruthTable`, and your definition for `printTruthTableValue` seems to be recursive and a bit confused. It would also be helpful if you have some more information about the problem. However, I expect you want something to the effect of:

```
public class TruthTables {

    public static void printTruthTable(String logicalOperation) {
        boolean rows[][] = {{true, true, false},
                            {true, false, false},
                            {false, true, false},
                            {false, false, false}};

        if (logicalOperation.equals("and")) {

            System.out.println("p  q  p AND q");
            System.out.println("-------------");

            for (boolean[] row : rows) {
                row[2] = row[0] && row[1];
            }

        } else if (logicalOperation.equals("or")) {
            // A similar sort of thing...

        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid boolean operator");
        }

        // Print table

        for (boolean[] row : rows) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (boolean value : row) {
                sb.append(value ? "T " : "F ");
            }

            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTruthTable("and");
        System.out.println();
        printTruthTable("or");
    }
}
```